# How to get list of installed and/or running extensions in Google Chrome from javascript

Tags: javascript, enumeration

I'm trying to improve the error reporting code on our site by adding information about installed plugins and extensions to the usual err, file, line and (sometimes) stacktrace details.

I can get a list of plugins from window.navigator.plugins, but how about extensions?
Is there a clean way of enumerating them from within a site's javascript?

Comment: i hope not javascript already tels the site to much info about the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, to my knowledge, just isn't possible. They're very careful to isolate extensions from each other, and [even from pages the extension is injected into](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment).

If you're worried about other extensions modifying the DOM in ways that break your extension, you might be able to look for symptoms of the extension(s) in question (e.g. added classNames, divs with certain classNames or ids), but that's basically it.